# Spring beans getting initialized twice - Spring Integration

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-integration

I'm trying to integrate my application with Spring Integration and experiencing that my custom spring beans are getting initialized twice, basically I see that the init method on these beans are getting called twice, once during the server startup and second time when HTTP request is made through DispatcherServlet.

Here is my web.xml configuration:

```
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>webapp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>webapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Here is my servlet-config.xml (with namespaces removed)

```
<import resource="springbeans-config.xml"/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.test"/>

<context:annotation-config/>

<int:channel id="inboundChannel"/>
<int:channel id="outboundChannel"/>

<http:inbound-gateway request-channel="inboundChannel" reply-channel="outboundChannel" name="/*" supported-methods="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE" reply-timeout="120000"/>

<int:chain input-channel="inboundChannel">
    <int:service-activator ref="clearContext"/>
    <int:service-activator ref="gatewayFilter"/>
    <int:service-activator ref="audit_logger"/>
    <int:service-activator ref="gatewayContextHandler" method="process"/>
</int:chain>
```

The custom file springbeans-config.xml containing all the bean definitions is imported as shown above. 
For e.g. the bean definition below would be invoked twice, during the server startup and while making HTTP request which gets invoked through DispatcherServlet.

```
    <bean name="sample" class="com.test.SampleImpl" init-method="init">
    <property name="xpathHelper" ref="XPathHelper"/>
    <property name="cacheManager" ref="cacheManager"/>
</bean>
```

Wondering what I'm missing here. Would appreciate any pointers / help on this. Thanks.

===============================================================

## UPDATE - SOLVED

loanshark example within SpringIntegration samples helped to resolve this issue.

Here is the updated web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>gateway</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>gateway</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Updated servlet-config.xml (with namespaces removed). Removed the import to bean definition file and component-scan and annotation-config in this file.

```
<http:inbound-gateway request-channel="inboundChannel" reply-channel="outboundChannel" name="/*" supported-methods="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE" reply-timeout="120000"/>

<int:chain input-channel="inboundChannel">
    <int:service-activator ref="clearContext"/>
    <int:service-activator ref="gatewayFilter"/>
    <int:service-activator ref="audit_logger"/>
    <int:service-activator ref="gatewayContextHandler" method="process"/>
</int:chain>
```

Renamed springbeans-config.xml to applicationContext.xml as per the sample, but I guess should not matter. Note, there are no imports in this file too.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test"/>

<context:annotation-config/>

<bean name="sample" class="com.test.SampleImpl" init-method="init">
    <property name="xpathHelper" ref="XPathHelper"/>
    <property name="cacheManager" ref="cacheManager"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: You're defining your bean in XML but I notice you're also scanning for beans using `component-scan` - do your classes have any annotations?

Comment: Yes, they do. I just add one of the bean here just as an example. There are other helper beans that are autowired within the service-activator components and present under springbeans-config.xml.

Comment: So to be clear, do you have beans that are both annotated using something like `@Component` _and_ defined in XML? Can you show full example for a single class that is being initialised twice?

Comment: Like @MattR said you most likely have annotated `SampleImpl` with instance `@Component` or something defining the bean twice. Choose one method of defining the bean.

Comment: Yes I confirm that SampleImpl is not annotated with @Component. It's only defined under springbeans-config.xml.

Answer (score 5):

Spring MVC Apps generally have 2 contexts; the servlet context and the root context.

It's generally good practice to put your "web" beans (@Controllers, views, Http inbound adatpers etc) in the servlet context and all the "business" beans in the root context.

Instead of importing your beans, you should put them in the root context using the context loader listener.

Beans in the servlet context can get references to beans in the root context, but not vice-versa.

The root context is loaded first; the filename doesn't matter but when using wildcards in the `contextConfigLocation` you need to be careful that the servlet context config is not picked up a second time.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. So, does the above "updated" configurations look good ? 

Basically, the servlet-config.xml contains all the Spring Integration components such as http inbound gateway, chains, routers, filters, service activators etc. 

All the helper beans needed by service activators would be under springbeans-config.xml. And both of servlet-config.xml and springbeans-config.xml would be independent of each other, in that they wont be importing each other either way.

Comment: Well, they're not really independent - the root context is the parent of the servlet context (allowing you to reference the beans from the service activator), but correct; no imports. It's personal preference; having all the SI components in the servlet context makes for a nice graph (if using the SI integration graph viewer). Some folks put just the http inbound adapter in the servlet context and the rest of the flow (starting with the first channel) in the root context.

Comment: Sure, I meant just from the configuration perspective with no specific imports. The only issue I face on having all the SI components inside servlet context is that those helper beans gets initialized twice, once during server startup & second time during an actual HTTP request .So having those beans (referenced by service activators) in the springbeans-config.xml which loads under root context helps. Ur last statement is a good point and allows me to think that even SI chains in the servlet-config can be moved in springbeans-config so they dont get initialized on every HTTP request. Correct?

Comment: The servlet context should not get reloaded on every request it only gets initialized when the servlet is first loaded - there must be something else going on.